# How to change Windows 10 task bar jump list color?

Tags: windows-10, themes, desktop-customization, jumplist, color-theme

I can change the colors of the task bar and with Classic Shell the start menu, but the Task Bar jump lists remain black. Is there a way to change the background color of these?